# PHP replace specific line in file

Tags: php, arrays, file, lines

I could actually not find any answers online. I have always searched online for answers when it comes to coding. Well..

I'm wondering how to change a specific line in a file with something else in PHP?

I have 4 lines looking like this:

```
$2y$10$hashedpassword
typewar
typewarMMM36634573323
84.2xx.xxx.xxx
```

I have recently started looking into cookies and that stuff, and wanted to be able to change the cookie (line 3) whenever the person logs in to the server or goes to index.php

I'm guessing something like this?

```
$user = 'typewar';
$GeneratedCookie = $user . 'MMM' . date('H', time()) * date('i', time()) * 333;
$lines = file('/path/to/identity/' . $user . '/identity.txt');
str_replace($lines[2], $GeneratedCookie . '/n');
```

Please help.

Comment: What happens when you try that code?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Have no clue, because it was just an example of what I thought the code might be looking like. I was struggling with this for a bit of time, and I don't want to even test this anymore haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure about your case. Please find the below idea and check it out.

```
$user = 'typewar';
$GeneratedCookie = $user . 'MMM' . date('H', time()) * date('i', time()) * 333;
$lines = file('/path/to/identity/' . $user . '/identity.txt');
print_r($lines); 
$lines[2] = $GeneratedCookie;
print_r($lines);
```

Comment: How do I execute the function?

Comment: just integrate the snippet with your code and `echo $lines;` before and after `implode` function.

Comment: okey, I tried: echo implode('/n',$lines_arr1); and it gave me the cookie, now how do I save it to the file on line 3?

Comment: What is the output before implode?

Comment: If you mean $lines_arr[2], gives me the same exact thing.

Comment: replace last line in my answer with `echo $lines; $lines = implode('/n',$lines_arr); echo $lines;` then post here the output.

Comment: First echo gives me: array. second echo gives me the cookie,

Comment: Please use my updated answer. It is working for me and should workout for you too...

Comment: It gave me two arrays where one of them contained the old info, and the other contained the new info

Comment: Then what you want?

Comment: Not quite what you wrote, but you helped me get on the right tracks! The only thing you have missed in your code is this: $lines[2] = $GeneratedCookie . "\n"; and file_put_contents('/path/to/identity/' . $user . '/identity.txt', $lines, true);